# Multiple Conditional compilation Macros with C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, conditional-compilation, compiler-flags

I'm trying to set up a makefile that compiles multiple segments of a rather lagrge program. In order to do so I want a Makefile to be able to pass MULTIPLE debug flags at once So I can test multiple different sets of functions together.

So in my Makefile :

```
debug:
    gcc -Wall -O -o my_malloc main.c -D experimental leak  <-- SECOND FLAG
    ./my_malloc
```

And in my C code I want to do  :

```
    #ifdef experimental
        printf("MALLOC PROGRAM IN DEBUGGING MODE\n");
    #endif
    //executing both conditionals at once in one line. 
    #ifdef leak
    puts("TESTING LEAK DETECTION");
    #endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-D` flag syntax is a bit different from what you wrote above. If you want to use more than one definition, use two different flags:

```
gcc -Wall -Dexperimental -Dleak -O -o my_malloc main.c
```